# AngularJS Submit button

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs

I'm trying to use a submit button to add new data and a pick winner button to pick new winner. Both buttons show , but when I click on them nothing happens.

Here is my index.html file.

## It's All About The Dogs!

```
<div ng-controller="DogCtrl">
<form ng-submit="addDog()">
<input type="text" ng-model="newDog.name">
<input type="submit" value="Add">
</form>

    <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="dog in dogs">
    {{dog.name}}
    <span ng-show="dog.winner" class="winner">WINNER</span>
</li>
</ul>

<button ng-click="drawWinner()">Draw Winner</button>
</div>

My js.coffee file.

@DogCtrl = ($scope) ->
   $scope.dogs = [
 {name: "Babytheboxer"}
 {name: "RaleightheJack"}
 {name: "Frankie"}
  ]

$scope.addDog = ->
  $scope.dogs.push($scope.newDog)
  $scope.newDog = {}

$scope.drawWinner = ->
  dog = $scope.dogs[Math.floor(Math.random()*$scope.dogs)]
  dog.winner = true
```

Comment: Can you debug, are the methods being called?

Comment: Did you add `<html ng-app>` ?

Comment: ng-app is not required if there are no modules defined.

Answer (score 0):

The only problem I see is in this line in your `js.coffee`:

```
dog = $scope.dogs[Math.floor(Math.random()*$scope.dogs)]
```

This should have given you some javascript errors because `$scope.dogs` is an array.  I'm assuming you want the array length here.

So try:

```
dog = $scope.dogs[Math.floor(Math.random()*$scope.dogs.length)]
```